# Submit form in jquery using scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there anyway you can submit a form using jquery? I have the following code which sends the id of a post when you scroll and was wondering if I could also submit some form values (ex, tv in this case) along with it.

Many thanks

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
            success: function(html){
                if (html) {
                    $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                } else {
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                });
            }
        });
```

The html for the form is as follows:

```
<select id="tv_dropdown" name="tv_dropdown" class="selecttv">
    <option value="">any tv</option>
    <option id="tv" value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
    <option id="tv" value="Panasonic">Panasonic</option>
    <option id="tv" value="Sony">Sony</option>
    <option id="tv" value="Sharp">Sharp</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When fixing your indentation, I noticed a syntax error.  You should rid yourself of the close paren after your else block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can pass data in `data` option of `ajax` options. Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "loadmore.php",
            type: "GET",//Set this to GET/POST etc as per your need.
            data: {
                 lastid: $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
                 tv: $("#tv_dropdown").val()
            },
            success: function(html){
                      if(html){
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                      }else{
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader')
                            .html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                      }
            }
    });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the data option to set the post data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "loadmore.php",
    data: {lastid : $(".postitem:last").attr("id"), tv: $("#tv_dropdown").val()}
    //...
```